# Initializing distributions for use across class methods (C++)

Tags: c++, class, random

I am trying to make a class that has a set of rng distributions as class attributes, with class methods having access to these distributions. Trying to follow the [example in the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution), I've distilled the problem to the following mwe. The code returns the errors `member "A::rd" is not a type name` and `no instance of overloaded function "std::uniform_real_distribution<_RealType>::operator() [with _RealType=double]" matches the argument list`.

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
private:
    // Declaration of variables...
 
    // Declare random number generators and distributions    
    random_device rd;
    mt19937 gen(rd());
    uniform_real_distribution<> zero_five_real_dist{0,5};

public:
    A(){
        // Initialization of variables...

        // Use distribution, here to print numbers
        for (int i; i<6; i++) cout << zero_five_real_dist(gen) << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }

    void print_nums(){
        for (int i; i<6; i++) cout << zero_five_real_dist(gen) << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    A a_obj;
    a_obj.print_nums();

    return 0;
}
```

I've found two possible work-arounds, but I'm not sure if they're any good.
The first is to just skip the use of the Mersenne twister engine,

```
class A{
private:
    mt19937 gen;
    uniform_real_distribution<> zero_five_real_dist{0,5};

public:
    A(){
        for (int i; i<6; i++) cout << zero_five_real_dist(gen) << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }

    void print_nums(){
        for (int i; i<6; i++) cout << zero_five_real_dist(gen) << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
};
```

and the other one is to seed the rng engine in every function call.

```
class A{
private:
    random_device rd;
    uniform_real_distribution<> zero_five_real_dist{0,5};

public:
    A(){
        mt19937 gen(rd());
        for (int i; i<6; i++) cout << zero_five_real_dist(gen) << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }

    void print_nums(){
        mt19937 gen(rd());
        for (int i; i<6; i++) cout << zero_five_real_dist(gen) << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
};
```

I'd greatly appreciate any input on how to make a good working implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code line:

```
    mt19937 gen(rd());
```

is ambiguous. I get that error message with GNU C++ v11.3:

```
q73126760.cpp:14:17: error: 'rd' is not a type
   14 |     mt19937 gen(rd());
      |                 ^~
q73126760.cpp: In constructor 'A::A()':
q73126760.cpp:22:59: error: invalid use of non-static member function 'std::mt19937 A::gen(int (*)())'
   22 |         for (int i; i<6; i++) cout << zero_five_real_dist(gen) << " ";
      |                                                           ^~~
```

Trouble is, one of the possible interpretations is that `gen` could be a member *function* of class A, *returning* some `mt19937` object. Your code is a new victim of the parsing rule known under the sulfurous name of [C++ Most Vexing Parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse): **the interpretation as a function declaration takes priority.**

And as `rd` is not a proper type, the interpretation as a function declaration ultimately fails, and the parser is unable to backtrack.

This can be fixed, for example, by forcing the compiler to take `rd()` as an initializer, using curly braces, like this:

```
    mt19937 gen{rd()};
```

Answer (score 2):

Initialize the generator in the constructor initializer list instead.

```cpp
A() : gen(rd()) {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: I can't upvote the answer, but I still wanted to say thanks for the initializer list tip!